# How to sign data using ECDSA algorithm, in C++ with OPENSSL?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a 32bytes SHA256 digest data and need to sign it with ECDSA. The private key is in a .pem file. I've already made it in console using the command: `openssl.exe dgst -sha256 -sign ecc.pem -out %sigfile% %data_file%`. Now i need to do it in c++ and the results I have been getting isn't the same as in console.

What are wrong in the code below, considering the command I uses in console?

```
bool sign(unsigned char *digest) {

    BIO *b_pem;
    EVP_PKEY* pkey2 = nullptr;
    const char * fileName = "ecc.pem";
    pkey2 = EVP_PKEY_new();
    b_pem = BIO_new_file(ecFileName, "rb");
    
    PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(b_pem, &pkey, NULL, NULL))

    unsigned char sign[200] = {0};
    EVP_MD_CTX *mctx;
    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");
    size_t signlen = 0;

    mctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    
    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(mctx, NULL, md, NULL, pkey)<=0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mctx, digest, 32) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(mctx, sign, &signlen) <=0) {
        return false;
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mctx);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the result? The example does not do anything with the calculated signature.

Comment: @SebastianDietrich the result that I get in the `sign` array is aways alternate on some different results. Sometimes returns 4, 38 or 70 bytes.  The last time I run this code I got four bytes: "30 46 02 21".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I've been searched for. Reading some project examples that used ECDSA from OpenSSL, I realised that I needed to convert the ASN1 encoded signature to raw signature bytes. So, here is the approach I used to get the wished result:

After sign the data by `EVP_DigestSignFinal()` function the code below was included and I could get the bytes in `as` and `ar` arrays.

```
ECDSA_SIG * ec_sig;
const BIGNUM *er = NULL;
const BIGNUM *es = NULL;
unsigned char *ar;
unsigned char *as;
size_t slen = EVP_PKEY_size(pkey);

ec_sig = d2i_ECDSA_SIG(NULL, (const unsigned char **)&sign, slen);
ECDSA_SIG_get0(ec_sig, &er, &es);

ar = (unsigned char*)malloc(BN_num_bytes(er));
as = (unsigned char*)malloc(BN_num_bytes(es));

BN_bn2bin(er, ar);
BN_bn2bin(es, as);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug handling the length of the buffer `sign`. You allocate 200 bytes but never tell `EVP_DigestSignFinal` about it, because you set `signlen = 0`. Therefore nothing is written to your buffer.

According to [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DigestSignUpdate.html) you need to set `signlen` to the maximum length available in the buffer and after the call it contains the number of bytes actually used.

Comment: Thanks by the sugestion @sebastian, but I tried that approach and the problem was the same.